# How to Search and Extract string in dataframe into new column if match on particular symbol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that has non readable alpha-numerical values for column names.

I want to extract entire email addresses from any column (cell) that has the `@` symbol in it. How would I search the entire dataframe regardless of column for the `@` symbol?

```
Input df:
    a.1   b.2        c.1      
    aa    a@a.com    12        
    bb    b@b.com    29       
    cc              
    dd    d@d.com
```

example df I want post extraction:

```
a.1   b.2        c.1       email
aa    a@a.com    12        a@a.com
bb    b@b.com    29        b@b.com
cc              
dd    d@d.com              d@d.com
```

Comment: Example input dataframe?

Comment: @Xukrao added input df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.contains`

```
df['email']=df.loc[df['b.2'].str.contains('@'),'b.2']
```

Seems like you need

```
df['email']=df[df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('@')).eq(True)].ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

Comment: The data will be different everytime so the code can not be column specific. Is there a way to search the entire dataframe for email addresses with the `@` symbol?

Comment: @RustyShackleford then using `df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('@'))`

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', u'occurred at index data.answers.1542213646975.answerRequired')` the `data.answers.etc` is the column name

Comment: @RustyShackleford ‘df.astye(str).apply(...)’

Comment: I tried this:

`df['email'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('@'))`

got error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)`